# Change majorIntervalScale when zooming in Core Plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am trying to change to core plot's majorIntervalScale while I'm zooming so as less items appear on the axis when zooming out and more appear when zooming in. I can't get this to work can anyone help please? Here's the code that I got so far. Thanks

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint
{
    return YES;
}

-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    self.graphScaleX = self.graphScaleX*newRange.lengthDouble;
    self.graphScaleY = self.graphScaleY*newRange.lengthDouble;

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;

    CPTXYAxis *y          = axisSet.yAxis;

    x.majorIntervalLength=CPTDecimalFromFloat(self.graphScaleX);
    y.majorIntervalLength=CPTDecimalFromFloat(self.graphScaleY);

    return newRange;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you always want to have the same number of tick marks no matter the length of the plot range. If so, use a different axis labeling policy instead of a delegate. The `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic` policy will find tick marks on "nice" numbers, but not necessarily the ends of the plot range. The `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions` will place equally-spaced ticks starting at one end of the plot range and continuing to the other. Both of these labeling policies use the `preferredNumberOfMajorTicks` to control how many tick marks to draw.